Failed Jito bundles
When Jito bundle is failed, how can I extract any reason of the fail? Some logs, maybe?
So far all I can see is the fact that it was failed
Sending request to: https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles
Request body: {
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "getInflightBundleStatuses",
  "params": [
    [
      "983c10d4f6f37b5478426351b8726d763a831f62ade8fe571c8738e8cc6afc98"
    ]
  ]
}
Response status: 200 OK
Response body: {
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "context": {
      "slot": 294824919
    },
    "value": [
      {
        "bundle_id": "983c10d4f6f37b5478426351b8726d763a831f62ade8fe571c8738e8cc6afc98",
        "landed_slot": null,
        "status": "Failed"
      }
    ]
  }
}

